# Why Is the Path Info Routing Not Working in ASP.NET MVC Example?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am reading the book *C# 6.0 and the .NET 4.6 Framework* and I was looking at the customized routing example `routes.MapRoute("Contact", "Contact/{*pathinfo}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" });`. The authors says that this should allow me to put in the url `http://localhost:64173/Home/Contact/Foo/Bar` and still be directed to the Contact page, because of the addition of `*pathinfo`. However, it is simply giving me a 404 Not Found. Specifically the authors state:

> ...adding {*pathinfo} to the pattern... allows any number of additional
>   URL parameters... Now when you enter the URL `http://localhost:64173/Home/Contact/Foo/Bar` it still shows the Contact page.

But I still get the 404 Error. I noted that `http://localhost:64173/Home/Contact/Foo` as well as `http://localhost:64173/Contact/Foo/parm1/parm2/parm3`. All of these redirect back to the Contact page. Here is what the full routing looks like:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute("Contact", "Contact/{*pathinfo}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" });
            routes.MapRoute("About", "About/{*pathinfo}", new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Thanks, I know this probably obvious, but I can't tell if the author made a mistake or if I'm missing something in my routes.

Note1: I also tried *pathInfo (with the "I" capitalized). This did not work either.

Note2: Navigating to `http://localhost:64173/Home/Contact/Foo`works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for asking this - Just spent 1/2 hour trying to track down what I had done wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't handle a request to `http://localhost/Contact/Foo` from a controller other than `ContactController` unless you inherit `ContactController` from something other than the base controller and do some implementation work to make that kind of Url rewrite happen. The excerpt to which you are referring simply allows you to pass parameters as Url segments without explicitly specifying all the parameters in the Url template.

Comment: So you're saying that when the book gives the example: http://localhost/Home/Contact/Foo/Bar they just meant http://localhost/Contact/Foo/Bar and should have excluded the Home controller part?

Comment: That's hard to say without more context, I don't know that book. I just know the MVC framework.

Comment: Sure, but I think I understand what you're saying. You're answer explains the behavior I'm seeing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered with this problem while reading the book

> Pro C# 7: With .NET and .NET Core 8th Edition by Andrew Troelsen and Phil Japiks.

There is wrote `"Add a new route"`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Contact", "Contact/{*pathinfo}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" });
```

and after you add a new route you need to open test URL:

`http://localhost:60466/Home/Contact/Foo/Bar`

but there is a mistake, you need to open URL above, without

> Home

like this `http://localhost:60466/Contact/Foo/Bar`